# How to hide Xfce4-panel in full screen mode?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel

I am playing a youtube video in Chrome and switched to full screen and it works fine but when I press the volume button on my keyboard to adjust the volume, I see that xfce4-panel appearing all of sudden even in full screen mode.
I tried using `wmctrl -r "xfce4-panel" -b add,below` and it is working. But when I place the command on startup, it is not working.
I have to manually every time enter this command in the Terminal for the effect.
I have also tried using `sleep 20 && wmctrl -r "xfce4-panel" -b add,below` command in the **Session and Startup** of Xfce with the view that the command will start after the xfce4-panel is loaded, but still it is of no use.

P.S: This happens even with VLC and other apps fullscreen mode also.
When I try to make a screenshot of this to post here, I see that the panel is disappearing in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote it in a shell file rather than directly pasting the command in the **Session and startup** like this.

```
#/bin/bash
sleep 10
wmctrl -r "xfce4-panel" -b add,below
```

and then added it to **startup** as `"/home/user/wmctrl.sh"` and it worked.
The `sleep 10` waits for 10 sec so that the xfce4-panel is loaded. Some systems may take longer, so the sleep value must be adjusted accordingly.
I suppose that **10** sec would be optimal for most systems since it will not take more than that for xfce4-panel to be loaded after logging in and also, typically no one would play a video and go full screen and adjust volume within 10 sec of system startup.